# Filter the XML for specific date from weather API

Tags: xml, api, excel, vba

How to filter the XML in Excel for specific date from this API?:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=16

The specific date in cell B10 is 2015-10-01, the API is offering data for 16-day forecast. I need to get the temperature, humidity, symbol name, and precipitation for that specific date.

I tried with =FILTERXML() but I can't find the xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

[image]

Formula in `E10` downwards:

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=16"),"/weatherdata/forecast/time[@day='"&TEXT($B$10,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"']/"&$C10&"/@"&$D10)
```

But the data of the web service is changing permanently.

Example XML:

```
<weatherdata>
 <location><name>London</name><type/><country>GB</country><timezone/><location altitude="0" latitude="51.50853" longitude="-0.12574" geobase="geonames" geobaseid="2643743"/></location><credit/><meta><lastupdate/><calctime>0.0117</calctime><nextupdate/></meta><sun rise="2015-09-20T05:43:44" set="2015-09-20T18:02:55"/>

 <forecast>
  <time day="2015-09-20">
    <symbol number="800" name="sky is clear" var="01d"/>
    <precipitation/>
    <windDirection deg="243" code="WSW" name="West-southwest"/>
    <windSpeed mps="3.96" name="Gentle Breeze"/>
    <temperature day="19.43" min="12.68" max="19.73" night="12.68" eve="17.24" morn="19.43"/>
    <pressure unit="hPa" value="1031.17"/>
    <humidity value="80" unit="%"/>
    <clouds value="clear sky" all="0" unit="%"/>
  </time>
```

XPATH to day temperature of day 2015-09-20:

```
/weatherdata/forecast/time[@day='2015-09-20']/temperature/@day
```